# How to get same session with Spring Security and Spring Session From multiple server

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm sorry that my english is still not so good.
Please bear with me, I hope you can understand my question..

---

I have two web servers.
(each web application is same)

Web servers are sharing one redis server.
And I use Spring Security and Spring Session.
When I login first server and access second server,
I want to login second server automatically, but it isn't.

I guess, because session id is different from different server ip.

- how to get same session id ?

### WEB.XML

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/jedis.xml
            </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Encoding -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Session Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

### jedis.xml

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value=""<!-- My Server IP --> />
    <property name="port" value="6379" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="redisPoolConfig" />
</bean>


<bean id="redisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000" />
    <property name="softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="-1" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000" />
</bean>

<!-- string serializer to make redis key more readible  -->
<bean id="stringRedisSerializer"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />

<!-- redis template definition  -->
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="keySerializer" ref="stringRedisSerializer" />
    <property name="hashKeySerializer" ref="stringRedisSerializer" />
</bean>
```

### spring-security.xml

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" >
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="changeSessionId">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/> <!-- I couldn't clear understand of this element-->
    </session-management>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/perBoard" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/per" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/perSearchTag" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/" 
                authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailureHandler"
                always-use-default-target="true" 
                username-parameter="j_username" 
                password-parameter="j_password"/>
                <!-- default-target-url="/board"  -->
    <logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class=".......LoginSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="sqlSession" ref="sqlSession" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="loginFailureHandler" class=".......LoginFailureHandler" />
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="......UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="sqlSession" ref="sqlSession" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: You cannot achieve session management across multiple servers using spring security. It requires a separate strategy. You can find more details here - http://serverfault.com/questions/32421/how-is-session-stickiness-achieved-across-multiple-web-servers/32453#32453

Comment: You can try to define session avare load balancer. Thus request with session id is sent to the app instance where the session id was generated.

Comment: thank you for your comment..
but i can't clearly understand..sorry,,
Can you give me some code level solution??

Comment: You need to share sessions between your web-containers. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561950/share-sessions-between-tomcat-instances-without-using-sticky-sessions

Comment: I have the same problem and do everything said on the link above. Why I having a different id session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like an old question. But, It looks like is possible to achieve the wanted behavior. Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/security.html for more details

### Create redis beans

```
<bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="port" value="${app.redis.port}" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${app.redis.hostname}" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
```

The above will create connection to `Redis` server with and will create a bean named `springSessionRepositoryFilter` which will replace the regular `HttpSession` implementation.

### Setup spring security

One can create `spring filter` via using `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy`
i.e :

```
<b:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
         <filter-chain pattern="/somelocation/" filters="none" />
         <filter-chain pattern="/someotherlocation"
            filters="springSessionRepositoryFilter, somemorespring filters"/>
    </filter-chain-map>
</b:bean>
```

**Note: The order of the filter for `spring security` is important and is not cover in this answer. BUT in order to be able to work with spring Session 
and redis, the very first filter has be to `springSessionRepositoryFilter`. More info about that can be found at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html**

### Setting up Http session

Edit `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-  class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This will allow `tomcat` to use `springSecurityFilterChain` before any filter and therefor it will allow to `springSessionRepositoryFilter` to be the first filter. Which will result with the `Spring session` magic to get the `session` from `redis` db

Using `Spring session + spring security` with out `custom spring filters` can be found at http://www.jayway.com/2015/05/31/scaling-out-with-spring-session/

Comment: @durron597 I have the same problems. But I don't have any clue on what's going on. I did the tutorial but they aren't sharing the same session. They are creating a new one.