# Spring Security using JDBC Sessions sharing same session across multiple web applications

Tags: java, session, spring-security, shared, spring-session

I'm currently using JDBC sessions across multiple applications, configured with Spring security. What I need is for all sessions of a same user to use the same session across all applications.

For example, user1 logs into his account into applicationA, this creates a session in the database correctly. After that, that same user1 logs into applicationB from a different browser, what I need is for that user to share its session across both applications, so that from applicationA the user can save something into its session and make it accesible from applicationB.

I know that I can achieve this if I manually change the SessionId cookie from the browser in applicationB, but what I need is for spring to do this on its own after login.

I have found a similar question here: [How to get same session with Spring Security and Spring Session From multiple server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447414/how-to-get-same-session-with-spring-security-and-spring-session-from-multiple-se/32458523)

But the answer is not correct.

**Additional info**
JDBC: Oracle
Configuration: All in Java

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that it would be solved by using OAuth2 and keeping their user data in an authorization server. Then both apps can access the same user data.

**Spring Session** is meant to enable session clustering, where you can have multiple instances of the same app sharing the external session store.